# DirectWrite has gone, fonts seem blurry and jagged after chrome update

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, fonts

this problem occurs after chrome update (ver52). As I learnt, DirectWrite was removed on chrome://flags, therefore I didn't do anything to solve the problem.

Especially small sized fonts are render blurry and jagged. When I design a web page fonts really bother me.

- I tried a lot of CSS tricks but no one solved the problem. (text-shadow, font-smoothing, transform3d, filter, zoom, scale and so on)
- Also I read that installed Helvetica font causes this problem, but I use win 7 and there isn't installed Helvetica font on my computer.
- I installed Chrome Canary; there is still problem on webpages.

So, has anybody got an idea to solve this problem.

Comment: without code and/or images to show the problem you're having (or think you're having), you're likely to not get a lot of responses. As a programming Q&A site, unless you can objectively described or illustrate what "seems blurry" means, questions about stuff like this are likely to get closed due to being impossible to answer.

Comment: Hi Mike, thank you for your advice. Of course you are right but this is one of the well-known topic on this website. There are lots of blurry and jagged font posts and there are lots of CSS solutions. So, generalIy people know this problem, therefore I didn't add any pic. But my problem arises from chrome's update. I think a lot of people suffer from this problem. That's why I posted this topic like that.